# Android studio cannot run any AVD

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on some Android project and want to test it on AVD. I created a device using Android Studio (3.1.3) it completed but couldn't run it printing an error: `Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Unknown AVD name [name_of_device], use -list-avds to see valid list`. So I type `emulator -list-avds` and see that the device exists. One time after closing and reinstalling Android Studio, I was able to run a device but the error appeared again after a short time. Another uninstalls did not solve the problem. Killing and starting adb server too. What is the reason for it?

Comment: Did you tried `adb kill-server && adb start-server`?

Comment: What is the android studio version that you are using

Comment: expanded my question to include these aspects :)

Comment: Ok, a workaround is to create an AVD by Android Studio, run it using CLI tools, run project using AS and select running device. But it does not explain why the program does not see devices created by itself